# Devise + JWT Not getting Correct User, after logging out from first user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

So my Problem is : When i sign in with User A(is Admin) it works fine and i can list the List of User in the database.

The problem occurs when i logout and sign in with user B(regular user)I can list the users as well which shouldn't happen (and current_user is still User A). BUT if i delete the httpOnly cookie that the rails application sends back and then request the list of user with the token from JWT with user B, I get 401 which is what i want.

I have an initializer

```
module Devise
  module Strategies
    class JWTAuthenticatable < Base
      def authenticate!
        token = get_token
        return fail(:invalid) unless token.present?

        payload = WebToken.decode(token)
        return fail(:invalid) if payload == :expire

        resource = mapping.to.find(payload['user_id'])
        return fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource

        success! resource       
      end

      private 

      def get_token 
        auth_header.present? && auth_header.split(' ').last
      end

      def auth_header
        request.headers['Authorization']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And My application controller is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, prepend: true
   before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Which only gets hit once from the first request but never any requests after that, and current_user stays stuck on the first signed in user. But again when the httpOnly cookie is deleted that Module gets hit and set current_user to User B.

I send JWT with every request but funny thing is when deleted after the first request i still get a response as if JWT exists.

Hope im explaining this correctly
Ive been searching for answers for about a week now. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in another post- Had to override devises store? to return false instead [Solution Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727777/rails-5-and-devise-how-i-disable-sessions-on-a-token-based-strategy-without-alt)